# QLibrary´s resolved function only has one argument?

Tags: c++, qt

Let´s consider this snippet from the Qt-Documentation:

```
QLibrary myLib("mylib");
typedef void (*MyPrototype)();
MyPrototype myFunction = (MyPrototype) myLib.resolve("mysymbol");
if (myFunction)
    myFunction();
```

This loads a .dll into memory and resolves the symbol "mysymbol", so I can use "myFunction". I got it working until here. I also can call myFunction(arg_1).

But when I call myFunction(arg_1, arg_2) I get an "too many arguments to function"-error.
So is it really only possible to call myFunction with 1 argument or is there something I´m missing?

Comment: Is `mysymbol` an `extern C` function? Are you adjusting your MyPrototype?

Comment: yes, I declared it with extern C. I don´t think I have to adjust the Prototype (did it anyway), because the error occurs at compile-time, so there´s no connection to the .dll yet.

Comment: If `mysymbol` takes two args (say `int`s), in this code (not in the library), you need to adjust your MyPrototype `typedef` to match that. That typedef and the actual function in the library _must_ match.

Comment: Seems like I got you wrong there. I did adjust the prototype now and it works, so thank you ^^

Comment: @Mat put your comment as an answer so it can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Let me rewrite Mat's comment. I took hours to find my problem as this.

suppose the dll:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void function1()
{
    //code
}
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int function2(int arg1)
{
    //code
}
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) char function3(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
{
    //code
}
```

the implementation should like this:

```
typedef void (*_function1)();
typedef int (*_function2)(int);
typedef char (*_function3)(int, int, int);

QLibrary myLib("mylib");

_function1 function1 = (_function1) myLib.resolve("function1");
_function2 function2 = (_function1) myLib.resolve("function2");
_function3 function3 = (_function1) myLib.resolve("function3");

if (function1 && function2 && function3)
{
    //implement them
    function1();
    int test = function2(123);
    char test1 = function3(1, 2, 3);
}
```